# React-Navigation: Navigating by pressing images

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I am trying to navigate screens by pressing on specific images on `SearchScreen.js`. Each image leads to a different screen. I am currently trying navigate from the first image to the screen `meo_sw.js`. However, I am not being able to do so and I don't undersand why. Here is the code of `SearchScreen.js` :

```
import React from 'react';
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, TextInput, Text, View, Image, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

function SearchScreen() {
 return (
<View style={styles.screen}>
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <TextInput style={styles.inputBox}
              underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)' 
              placeholder="Procura aqui"
              placeholderTextColor = "black"
              selectionColor="black"
              keyboardType="default"/>
  </View>
  <View style={styles.teste}> 
    <Text style={styles.festivais}>Recomendados</Text>
    <ScrollView horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} style={styles.festivais_lista}>
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Image source={require('../assets/images/meo_sudoeste.png')} style={styles.image} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('meo_sw')}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Image source={require('../assets/images/vodafone_coura.png')} style={styles.image} onPress={() => {}}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Image source={require('../assets/images/superbock_superrock.png')} style={styles.image} onPress={() => {}}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Image source={require('../assets/images/nos_primavera.png')} style={styles.image} onPress={() => {}}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Image source={require('../assets/images/rock_in_rio.png')} style={styles.image} onPress={() => {}}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Image source={require('../assets/images/edp_cooljazz.png')} style={styles.image} onPress={() => {}}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
</View>
  );
}

SearchScreen.navigationOptions = {
  title: 'Procurar',
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 //I took this part off because it is useless for this especific question
});

export default SearchScreen;
```

And here is the screen 'meo_sw.js':

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const meo_sw = props => {

return(
    <View style={styles.header}>
        <Text style={styles.texto}>Meo Sudoeste</Text>
    </View>
    )
};

const styles=StyleSheet.create({
header:{
    width:'100%',
    height:90,
    paddingTop:36,
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
},
texto:{
    color:'white',
    fontSize: 18
}
})

export default meo_sw;
```

Please help me

Comment: Try adding onPress on TouchableOpacity

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is wrapping the `Image` in `TouchableWithoutFeedback` and then adding the `onPress` on the `TouchableWithoutFeedback`. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback

Comment: Yes sir, it is an alternative. However I prefered to use the default one, wich is the TouchableOpacity, simply because I am just focused on solving the probem that I anounced here.

Comment: Add the onPress to the TouchableOpacity not the Image.

Answer (score 0):

use hookrouter instead, the modern alternative to react-router: https://www.npmjs.com/package/hookrouter

```
...
import { useRoutes, usePath, A} from "hookrouter";

navigate('/about');
```

to answer OP question about navigating from image click:

```
...
 <TouchableOpacity>
     <Image source={require('../assets/images/meo_sudoeste.png')} style={styles.image} onPress={() => navigate('/meo_sw')}/>
 </TouchableOpacity>
...
```

Comment: What is the same error? You didn't mention one to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You should add:

```
function xx({navigation}) {}
```

It worked for me at least!

Answer (score 0):

I think there could be these issues

- First pass the `navigation` in the `function searchScreen({navigation})`.
- Then there is no `onPress` prop available in `<Image>` component so use `onPress` on `<TouchableOpacity>`.